# why does maven profile get activated activated when other value specified

Tags: maven

Given profiles:

```
<profile>
  <id>default</id>
  <activation>
    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    <property>
      <name>env</name>
      <value>default</value>
    </property>
  </activation>
</profile>

<profile>
  <id>alternative</id>
  <activation>
    <property>
      <name>env</name>
      <value>alternative</value>
    </property>
  </activation>
</profile>
```

why does `default` gets activated on `-Denv=somethingCompletelyDifferent` ? I would expect it to be activated when the `env` is empty or equal to `default`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Maven documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html):

> This profile will automatically be active for all builds unless another profile in the same POM is activated using one of the previously described methods. All profiles that are active by default are automatically deactivated when a profile in the POM is activated on the command line or through its activation config.

So as long as no other profile gets active the one with activeByDefault will always be on. So only with `-Denv=alternative` you can disable the default one.